# can't extract a substring with regex

Tags: regex, git, bash, sed, githooks

I'm trying to write a prepare-commit-msg hook for git. The script should do following steps :

1. Get the current git branch name (working)
2. Extract the `issue-id` (not working)
3. Check if the `issue-id` is already in the commit msg
4. If not, insert `[issue-id]` before the commit message

The `issue-id` has this pattern `[a-zA-Z]+-\d+` and the branch name should be something like `feature/issue-id-my-small-description`.

But for now, the extraction part is not ok...

Here is my prepare-commit-msg script :

```
# Regex used to extract the issue id
REGEX_ISSUE_ID="s/([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)//"

# Find current branch name
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

# Extract issue id from branch name
ISSUE_ID= $BRANCH_NAME | sed -r $REGEX_ISSUE_ID

# Check if the issue id is already in the msg
ISSUE_IN_COMMIT=$(grep -c "\[$ISSUE_ID\]" $1)

# Check if branch name is not null and if the issue id is already in the commit msg
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && ! [[ $ISSUE_IN_COMMIT -ge 1 ]]; then 
  # Prefix with the issue id surrounded with brackets
  sed -i.bak -e "1s/^/[$ISSUE_ID] /" $1
fi
```

**Edit to add in-/output example**

Input `$1` is the git commit message which is something like

```
fix bug on login
```

or

```
fix MyIssue-234 which is a bug on login
```

Output should be the input with the issue id i.e. :

```
[MyIssue-123] fix bug on login
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the **input** and desired **output**

Comment: @PedroLobito post updated. I think the way I use my regex w/ sed is wrong

Comment: Inian's now-deleted answer shows the main problem. You should either close this and open a new question, or edit the question to show both the new script *and* what happens when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what and why you do as you do, but this is the closest I got by fixing what I thought is to be corrected in your code:

```
# Regex used to extract the issue id
REGEX_ISSUE_ID="s/\[([a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+)\].*/\1/"

# Find current branch name
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
if [[ -z "$BRANCH_NAME" ]]; then
    echo "No brach name... "; exit 1
fi

# Extract issue id from branch name
ISSUE_ID=$(echo "$BRANCH_NAME" | sed -r "$REGEX_ISSUE_ID")

# Check if the issue id is already in the msg
ISSUE_IN_COMMIT=$(echo "$@" | grep -c "^\[*$ISSUE_ID\]*")

# Check if branch name is not null and if the issue id is already in the commit msg
if [[ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ]]; then
    if [[ $ISSUE_IN_COMMIT -gt 0 ]]; then 
        shift # Drop the issue if from the msg
    fi
    # Prefix with the issue id surrounded with brackets
    MESSAGE="[$ISSUE_ID] $@"
fi

echo "$MESSAGE"
```

where `$@` is all the words that you provide after "fix" (ex. `"$@" = "bug" "on" "login"`). The rest I hope you understand after you compare it to your original code.

Comment: After some tryouts, I fixed my regexp for sed and this one worked. Thanks